# For loop error with parameters (x, y) to proceed to draw html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

There are 2 loops in which each one has different results, and with those loops, the axes (x, y) of the canvas boxes are specified. But at the time of entering the parameters, I am not clear about how to organize the loops with the canvas path, or a way in which it is executed properly according to the for.

```
bucle de eje x = for (var i = 9; i <= 19; i++) {
                    x = 50*i;
                  }

bucle de eje y = for (var i = 10; i >= 1; i--) {
                y = 50*i;
                }
```

```js
function funcDelRect(){
        
    // for eje x 
        for (var i = 9; i <= 19; i++) {
            x = 50*i;
            console.log("1: " + x);
        
            console.log('--------------------');

        // for eje y 
        for (var i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {
                y = 50*i;
                console.log("2: " + y);

      // Canvas Rect();
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasGEO');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(x, y, 25, 25); 
            ctx.fillStyle = "gold";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
            }
        }   
    }
```

```html
<canvas style="background-color: lightgreen; border: 1px solid black" id="canvasGEO" width="1000" height="700"></canvas>

    <button type="submit" id="agreeRect" onclick="funcDelRect()">Subir cuadros</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same variable to count the inner loop that counts the outer loop.

The result is that the outer loop will loop around with `i` set to the value -1, and thus will never exit

```
for (var i = 9; i <= 19; i++) {  // Using i = 9
    for (var i = 10; i >= 0; i--) { // using i again starts at 10
    }
    // i is now === -1
} // outer loop adds one to i so it is now 0 but will never exit i > 19
```

Either use two separate variables

```
var i,j;
for (i = 9; i <= 19; i++) { 
    for (j = 10; j >= 0; j--) {
    }
}
```

Or use locally scoped variables

```
for (let i = 9; i <= 19; i++) { 
    for (let i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {  // this i is scoped to this loop and is not
                                     // the same variable as the outer i
        // NOTE you can not access the outer i
    }
}
```

### Hoisting

When you use [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) to declare variables always put them at the top of the function ([Hoist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) them) to avoid errors like this.

### Declaration types and scope.

For more on [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) and variable declarations [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) and [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)